# Simple Python Code is not running

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

My python code is not running. I used Linux Ubuntu on Virtual Box. Can be problem for python? I use vim text editor

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def talk(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("SubClass must be implemented abstract method")

class Cat(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        Pet.__init__(self, name, age)

    def talk(self):
        return "Meow"

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        Pet.__init__(self, name, age)

    def talk(self):
        return "Hav Hav"

def main():
    pets = [Cat("jess",3),Dog("aslan",2),Cat("miyav",5), Pet("theped",2)]

    for pet in pets"
        print "Name" + pet.neme + "Age: " + str(pet.age) + "says: " + pet.talk()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting an error about invalid syntax.

[image: This is error]

Comment: Hi, could you copy and paste your code instead of using screenshots?

Comment: Take a closer look at that line being pointed out... Isn't it something *missing* at the end of it? And quote a few more.

Comment: Insert `:` after `def talk(self)` and after `for pet in pets`...

Comment: if you add `:` after def talk(self), problem solved, then, you can erase the question, is off topic in this site, also, your missing rep points will return to you. Just an advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a colon after (self). As usual try to read the error message, as it clearly says that there is a problem with the syntax. And don't immediately assume that there is a problem with your tool.

Comment: ... unless you count your spectacles as a tool :-)

Comment: Also, after the for loop and `def talk()` in the dog class.